# Leverage browser caching not working after updating .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have website in wordpress and i updated my .htaccess file with following rule.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Now when i checked my website performance with google insight. it still giving me error for **leverage browser caching**

Comment: Check in your php.ini configuration whether mod_expires is disabled